# 2 LEFT JOINs with WHERE clause not working

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to make a query with 2 joins which both need a WHERE clause. I noticed that this doesn't work and that I can only add a WHERE at the end of the join. So I would like to know how I can do this best instead..

This is my current query which doesnt accept the WHERE in the first join:

```
SELECT  
    p.id, p.username, p.date, p.subject, p.year, p.brand, 
    p.model, p.type, p.bodywork, p.text, p.image, p.chassis, COUNT(c.id) AS answers
FROM 
    posts_tbl AS p
LEFT JOIN 
    post_reply_tbl AS c ON c.post_id = p.id WHERE c.type = 1 AND c.type = 3
LEFT JOIN 
    post_reply_tbl AS a ON a.post_id = p.id WHERE a.type = 2
GROUP BY p.id
```

Comment: That's not where the `WHERE` clauses go.  Correct SQL syntax is `SELECT ... FROM ... [LEFT] JOIN ... ON ... [AND ...] WHERE ... [AND ...]`

Comment: Oh yea thats true but I do need to specify the type for those tables

Comment: Also `c.type = 1 AND c.type = 3` doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change that to an `AND` not a `WHERE`:

```
SELECT  p.id, p.username, p.date, p.subject, p.year, p.brand, 
    p.model, p.type, p.bodywork, p.text, p.image, p.chassis, COUNT(c.id) AS answers
FROM posts_tbl AS p
LEFT JOIN post_reply_tbl AS c 
    ON c.post_id = p.id 
    AND c.type = 1 AND c.type = 3
LEFT JOIN post_reply_tbl AS a 
    ON a.post_id = p.id 
    AND a.type = 2
GROUP BY p.id
```

I think you need to alter this slightly though because `c.type` cannot have two values at the same time:

```
SELECT  p.id, p.username, p.date, p.subject, p.year, p.brand, 
    p.model, p.type, p.bodywork, p.text, p.image, p.chassis, COUNT(c.id) AS answers
FROM posts_tbl AS p
LEFT JOIN post_reply_tbl AS c 
    ON c.post_id = p.id 
    AND c.type IN (1, 3)  -- changed to use an OR
LEFT JOIN post_reply_tbl AS a 
    ON a.post_id = p.id 
    AND a.type = 2
GROUP BY p.id
```

If you want the `c.type` to be equal to both `1` and `3`, then you might want to consider using:

```
SELECT  p.id, p.username, p.date, p.subject, p.year, p.brand, 
    p.model, p.type, p.bodywork, p.text, p.image, p.chassis, c.answers
FROM posts_tbl AS p
LEFT JOIN
(
    select COUNT(c.id) answers, c.post_id
    from post_reply_tbl c
    where c.type in (1, 3)
    group by c.post_id
    having COUNT(distinct type) = 2
) AS c 
    ON c.post_id = p.id 
LEFT JOIN post_reply_tbl AS a 
    ON a.post_id = p.id 
    AND a.type = 2
```

Just a following up note on your query, since you are using a `GROUP BY` on only one column, MySQL decides what values for the other columns are returned and the values can be unexpected.  The only way you can be sure of the value being returned is to aggregate each column or group by them.  (see [MySQL Extensions to GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html))

From the MySQL Docs:

> MySQL extends the use of GROUP BY so that the select list can refer to nonaggregated columns not named in the GROUP BY clause. ... You can use this feature to get better performance by avoiding unnecessary column sorting and grouping. However, this is useful primarily when all values in each nonaggregated column not named in the GROUP BY are the same for each group. The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate. Furthermore, the selection of values from each group cannot be influenced by adding an ORDER BY clause. Sorting of the result set occurs after values have been chosen, and ORDER BY does not affect which values the server chooses.

For this reason it might be better to use a subquery to get the `count()` then you will be sure you are returning the correct result for the remaining columns.:

```
SELECT  p.id, p.username, p.date, p.subject, p.year, p.brand, 
    p.model, p.type, p.bodywork, p.text, p.image, p.chassis, c.answers
FROM posts_tbl AS p
LEFT JOIN
(
    select COUNT(c.id) answers, c.post_id
    from post_reply_tbl c
    where c.type in (1, 3)
) AS c 
    ON c.post_id = p.id 
LEFT JOIN post_reply_tbl AS a 
    ON a.post_id = p.id 
    AND a.type = 2
```

Comment: you are just sweeping this website with your prompt answers. No chance for any answers for me :)

Comment: Yep. The entire "ON" is the join condition, and can have multiple parts.

Comment: How can `c.type = 1 AND c.type = 3`?  That should be `AND (c.type = 1 OR c.type = 3)` or `c.type IN (1,3)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can either add all the where conditions at the end of the query:

```
SELECT  p.id, p.username, p.date, p.subject, p.year, p.brand, 
    p.model, p.type, p.bodywork, p.text, p.image, p.chassis, COUNT(c.id) AS answers
                FROM posts_tbl AS p
                LEFT JOIN post_reply_tbl AS c ON c.post_id = p.id 
                                LEFT JOIN post_reply_tbl AS a ON a.post_id = p.id 
WHERE a.type = 2
   AND c.type = 1 AND c.type = 3
GROUP BY p.id
```

Or use AND in the join conditions:

```
SELECT  p.id, p.username, p.date, p.subject, p.year, p.brand, 
    p.model, p.type, p.bodywork, p.text, p.image, p.chassis, COUNT(c.id) AS answers
                FROM posts_tbl AS p
                LEFT JOIN post_reply_tbl AS c ON c.post_id = p.id AND c.type = 1 AND c.type = 3
                                LEFT JOIN post_reply_tbl AS a ON a.post_id = p.id AND a.type = 2
                                GROUP BY p.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put all terms in one where clause

```
SELECT p.id, p.username, p.date, p.subject, p.year, p.brand, 
p.model, p.type, p.bodywork, p.text, p.image, p.chassis, COUNT AS answers
FROM posts_tbl AS p
LEFT JOIN post_reply_tbl AS c ON c.post_id = p.id 
LEFT JOIN post_reply_tbl AS a ON a.post_id = p.id 
WHERE a.type = 2 AND c.type = 1 AND c.type = 3
GROUP BY p.id
```